# when developing locally, does it make a difference if the context is '/' or '/appname/'?

Tags: java, servlets

when developing locally, does it make a difference if the context is '/' or '/appname/' ?

Assuming you will be deploying to http://www.example.com

I like it when my local url is:

http://localhost:8080/

but just want to know if the url is

http://localhost:8080/appname/

if it makes any difference?

Comment: Removed Spring-related tags, since this isn't Spring-specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) to figure out where the app is deployed at runtime so *in theory* it's possible.

In practice nobody does this and the context path is assumed in links, images, form actions, etc.

Comment: so your saying, in practice, people develop locally using / or /appname ?

Comment: @Blankman I usually develop locally to the same context root used in production, which is (99% of the time) `/`.

Comment: I'll object to "nobody does this" - every webapp my company produces uses macros for generating urls which under the cover use getContextPath()

Comment: @matt: you're in a pretty small minority then.

Comment: @cletus I try to encourage the best practice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying on the root, then the [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) will always resolve to `/`.

Your interest is the *pathinfo*. In a Filter you can reveal it by [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and in a Servlet also by [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you're planning to deploy with Apache (or something else that handles the initial HTTP request) in front of your app server (tomcat?), it doesn't matter: Apache config will sort that aspect out.

If you plan to go with just your app server in production, no HTTP server in front of it, I would say it *does* matter, as you want to make sure your app's available at www.example.com, not example.com/appname.

By "does matter" I mean there's inherently some value in having your local server configuration the same as the production one to reduce nasty surprises in the future; you can of course configure local differently to production.

You also need to bear in mind: will you have multiple Java webapps running under a single app server? If so, plan for how you'll deploy those in production.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be careful using the root context as there is the possibility when coding to assume you are in the root context and result in a webapp that will only run in the root context.
By using a named context you avoid this possibility.